# Spring data JPA query behaves unexpectedly

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have these entities:

```
public class Order_status_sas {
   private Order_sas order;
   private Date lastModified;
   ...
}

public class Order_sas {
   private long id;
   ...
}
```

My CrudRepository:

```
public interface StatusesWareHouseRepository extends CrudRepository<Order_status_sas, Long> {
   Order_status_sas findFirstByOrderIdOrderByLastModifiedDesc(long id);
}
```

I expect that method `findFirstByOrderIdOrderByLastModifiedDesc` would return first row from table `Order_status_sas`, where `order.id = <some_id>` sorted by field `lastModified`, but in log I see this query:

```
Hibernate: select ... 
       from order_status_sas a 
          left outer join orders_sas b 
            on a.order_id=b.id 
       where b.id=? 
       order by a.last_modified desc
```

This query does not return me one row, but returns a list of rows. It seems that Spring Data do not look at word `First` in my method name. Also, I get an Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: 
result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
```

Please, tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I achieve my purpose?

**EDITED:**
I edited my `StatusesWareHouseRepository` with custom query:

```
@Query("select s from Order_status_sas s where s.order.id = ?1 order by s.lastModified desc limit 1")
Order_status_sas findFirstByOrderIdOrderByLastModifiedDesc(long id);
```

but the query, executed by Hibernate, haven't changed. It looks like this:

```
select ... 
from order_status_sas s 
where s.order_id=? 
order by s.last_modified desc
```

Comment: Actually, it looks exactly like Spring Data IS looking at the word `first` in your method name, or you wouldn't be getting an `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`.  If you don't have the ability to alter the domain model, you're likely going to have to use a `Criteria` query or a manual query.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I understood @PriduNeemre point. Lets leave the DB model and come back to the JPA question. Here is another example:

```
@Entity
public class Client {
   ....
}

public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Integer> {

Client findFirstByOrderByNameDesc();
}
```

Hibernate query still looks like this:

```
select ... 
from clients c 
order by c.name desc
```

Comment: As I said earlier, the only thing missing from this (and the previous) query is the SQL  `LIMIT 1` clause. As to how or if this could be achieved - hopefully someone with more extensive knowledge of Spring's newer features will come and help out. In the meantime, though, you could use some of the solutions & workarounds mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `@Query` annotation (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html)) on top of your  `findFirstByOrderIdOrderByLastModifiedDesc(..)` method to specify the expected behaviour by hand? A (non-related) example on how this could work:

```
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT I FROM Invoice I JOIN I.customer C JOIN C.user U WHERE 
        U.username = :username")
    public List<Invoice> findInvoicesByUsername(@Param("username")
        String username);
}
```

Note that the query language used in the annotation body is in fact [JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html), not SQL. For more examples on the `@Query` annotation, see the Spring Data docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

PS: I'm also having conflicted feelings about your domain object structure, *i.e.* whether an instance of `Order_sas` should really be stored in an instance of `Order_status_sas` - shouldn't it be the other way around? Normally you would want to store the reference objects in your main domain object, not *vice versa*. (*There's a slight possibility that I'm just not getting it right, though.*)

EDIT: I would even go as far as to say that considering your current domain model, Hibernate is doing everything right except missing a LIMIT 1 clause to limit the expected resultset to one single row. The query itself is extremely inefficient, though, and could be improved by fixing your skewed domain model.

Comment: If'd use `@Query` ofcourse I will achieve the expected behaviour, but I wanted to use this method, because according documentation, I can achieve this purpose. I dissagree with you about my object structure. It's OneToMany relationship where one Order has many Order_status'es. I wanted to know what I was doing wrong that my method did not behave as stated in documentation.

Comment: IMO it's behaving incorrectly because you have provided it with a non-standard domain model. Surely an `Order_status` can also be connected to multiple `Order`s? Thus you are no longer dealing with a one-to-many relationship, but a many-to-many relationship. The standard procedure for handling many-to-many relationships is, as I'm sure you're aware, via the creation of [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Thus, a "standard" domain model would consist of something like the following: `Order_sas`, `Order_status_link_sas` (the junction table), `Order_status_sas`.

Comment: Note that `Order_status_link_sas` is not a *perfect* name for the junction table, but more of a quick example. With some guesswork you could probably come out with a better, more meaningful name for it.

Comment: I realy don't understand why my model is non-standart. Please, look, it is exactly as shown here: [OneToMany](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany). Please, explain why do you think that I'm dealing with many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @polis: I think I have already given a pretty comprehensive explanation as to what is wrong with your data model. However, let me give this another shot: the example you have provided does indeed describe a one-to-many relationship. A verbal description for the relationships involved would be: "An employee can own MULTIPLE phones; a phone can belong to ONE employee". In your case, however, the relationship could be worded as: "An order can be described by MULTIPLE order statuses; An order status can be attributed to MULTIPLE orders". Thus, you effectively create a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @polis: It is a bit unclear, however, why you would have want to have an `Order` that is connected to multiple `Order_status`es at the same time. In most cases you would have the following description: "An order can be described by ONE order status (at a time); AN order status can be attributed to MULTIPLE orders", which is again a one-to-many relationship. Sometimes though, you might want to store historic data in which case the aforementioned many-to-many relationship comes into play.